# Facebook Graph API : get larger pictures in one request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using [the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to make some tests. That's a good tool.

I want to get the user's friend list, with friends' names, ids and pictures. So I type :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,picture,name
```

But picture is only 50x50, and I would like a larger one in this request.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

you do not need to pull 'picture' attribute though. there is much more convenient way, the only thing you need is userid, see example below;

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=large

p.s. type defines the size you want

plz keep in mind that using token with basic permissions, /me/friends  will return list of friends only with id+name attributes

Comment: But i'm not agree with you last sentence : with basic permission, you can access more than id+name attribute, ex : https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor

Comment: uhm, what about "in one request"?

Comment: U can also use full_picture instat of picture.

Comment: "message": "(#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher",

Answer (score 209):

As described in [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129804577163441) on Facebook, you can also request specific image sizes now via the new API "[field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)" syntax.

Like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/____OBJECT_ID____?fields=picture.type(large)
```

Comment: Indeed. fields=picture.width(640) is even better.

Comment: It seems the Facebook Graph API changed their api. Facebook responsed "Subfields are not supported by picture" when I tried to use your suggestion.

Comment: getting error: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Comment: See the ?field=full_picture,attachments for 2.x queries

Comment: After going through 5 and more topics, finally found correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: You saved me from doing batch request, thx! Don't understand why I didn't found it in docs.

Comment: With version 2.5, I'm also seeing  "Subfields are not supported by picture". Is there a workaround?

Comment: With New Facebook Changes, unable to get the larger image. Any hint anyone?

Answer (score 84):

The best way to get all friends (who are using the App too, of course) with correct picture sizes is to use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion), either with one of the size tags (square, small, normal, large):

```
/me/friends?fields=picture.type(large)
```

*(edit: this does not work anymore)*

...or you can specify the width/height:

```
me/friends?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)
```

Btw, you can also write it like this:

```
me?fields=friends{picture.type(large)}
```

Comment: thanx for the info, i will update the answer. full_picture does not seem to work for friends though: /me/friends?fields=full_picture - do you have any idea how this would be possible?

Answer (score 40):

You can set the size of the picture in pixels, like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,picture.width(500).height(500)
```

In the similar manner, `type` parameter can be used

```
{user-id}/?fields=name,picture.type(large)
```

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)

> type 
>   enum{small, normal, album, large, square}

Answer (score 34):

Change the array of fields `id,name,picture` to `id,name,picture.type(large)`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)&access_token=<the_token>
```

Result:

```
{
   "id": "130716224073524",
   "name": "Julian Mann",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15032818_133926070419206_3681208703790460208_n.jpg?oh=a288898d87420cdc7ed8db5602bbb520&oe=58CB5D16"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How is 200 x 200 large?

Comment: In latest (2.10) Graph API is not "large" size available: `Graph returned an error: (#100) For field 'picture': type must be one of the following values: thumbnail, small, album`

Answer (score 20):

You can also try getting the image if you want it based on the height or width

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?height=

OR

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?width=

The values are by default in pixels you just need to provide the int value

Answer (score 20):

I researched Graph API Explorer extensively and finally found full_picture

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/$id/posts?fields=picture,full_picture
```

P.S. I noticed that full_picture won't always provide full size image I want. 'attachments' does

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/$id/posts?fields=picture,full_picture,attachments
```

Comment: this is only show width:720px. u r only large photo find like this. 

for biggest https://graph.facebook.com/photo_id u can see 6 different sizes photo.

Comment: i just tested this with the friends endpoint and it did not work

Answer (score 10):

Hum... I think I've found a solution.

In fact, in can just request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name
```

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (section "Pictures"), url of profile's photos can be built with the user id

For example, assuming user id is in $id :

```
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=square"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=small"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=normal"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=large"
```

But it's not the final image URL, so if someone have a better solution, i would be glad to know :)

Comment: PICTURE SIZE TYPES: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 5):

You can specify `width` & `height` in your request to Facebook graph API: `http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?width=500&height=500`

Answer (score 4):

You can size it as follows.

Use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=picture.type(large)
```

For details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 2):

From `v2.7`, `/<picture-id>?fields=images` will give you a list with different size of the images, the first element being the full size image.

I don't know of any solution for multiple images at once.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I made a request with `picture.type(full_picture)`:

> "(#100) For field 'picture': type must be one of the following
>   values: small, normal, album, large, square"

When I make the request with `picture.type(album)` and `picture.type(square)`, responses me with an image 50x50 pixel size.

When I make the request with `picture.type(large)`, responses me with an image 200x200 pixel size.

When I make the request with `picture.width(800)`, responses me with an image 477x477 pixel size.

with `picture.width(250)`, responses 320x320.

with `picture.width(50)`, responses 50x50.

with `picture.width(100)`, responses 100x100.

with `picture.width(150)`, responses 160x160.

I think that facebook gives the images which resized variously when the user first add that photo.

> What I see here the API for requesting user Image does not support
>   resizing the image requested. It gives the nearest size of image, I think.

Comment: True...  "picture.type(large)" also gave me a 200x200 - not very large I must say

Answer (score 1):

In pictures URL found in the Graph responses (the "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/" ones), just replace the default "_s.jpg" by "_n.jpg" (? normal size) or "_b.jpg" (? big size) or "_t.jpg" (thumbnail).

Hacakable URLs/REST API make the Web better.

Comment: Seems to always give "An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.27f74317.14274.604fb0" now unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

rest-fb users (square image, bigger res.):
Connection myFriends = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "public_profile,email,first_name,last_name,gender,picture.width(100).height(100)"));

Answer (score 0):

I think that as of now the only way to get large pictures of friends is to use FQL. First, you need to fetch a list of friends:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends

Then parse this list and extract all friends `ids`. When you have that, just execute the following FQL query:

```
SELECT id, url FROM profile_pic WHERE id IN (id1, id2) AND width=200 AND height=200
```

`200` here is just an exemplary size, you can enter anything. You should get the following response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": ..., 
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/..."
    }, 
    {
      "id": ..., 
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/..."
    }
  ]
}
```

With each url being the link to a 200x200px image.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but i tried this one to solve my problem. it returns large image.
It is not the perfect fix but you can try this one.

**https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/OBJECT_ID/picture?access_token=XXXXX**

Comment: Just add one more parameter to the request: type=large. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the size of the image by changing the pixel size from the url in each json object as follows :

for example I change **s480x480** to be **s720x720**

Before : 
https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-9/q71/s480x480/10454308_773207849398282_283493808478577207_n.jpg

After :
https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/10454308_773207849398282_283493808478577207_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

JS styled variant.
Just set enormous large picture width and you will get the largest variant.

```
FB.api(
  '/' + userId,
  {fields: 'picture.width(2048)'},
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      console.log(response.picture.data.url);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use full_picture instead of picture key to get full size image.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: From Graph API v8.0 you `must provide the access token` for every UserID request you do.

**Hitting the graph API:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture?height=1000&access_token=<any_of_above_token>
```

**With firebase:**

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl() + "/picture?height=1000&access_token=" +
  loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
```

You get the token from `registerCallback` just like this

```
       LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl() + "/picture?height=1000&access_token=" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Fb on Login", "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e("Fb on Login", "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });
```

This is what documentation says:

> Beginning October 24, 2020, an access token will be required for all
> UID-based queries. If you query a UID and thus must include a token:
>
> - use a User access token for Facebook Login authenticated requests
> - use a Page access token for page-scoped requests
> - use an App access token for server-side requests
> - use a Client access token for mobile or web client-side requests
>
> We recommend that you only use a Client token if you are unable to use
> one of the other token types.