# Get full sized picture from facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I'm using the graph api endpoint `/PAGE_ID/posts` to get all posts from a facebook page.
Now I want the full sized image from these posts. The picture property of the returned objects gives me only a cropped version of that image.

With the object id from these posts and the API endpoint `/OBJECT_ID/picture` I get the only the small, normal and album sized version of the picture. But with a little modification to the URL I managed to get the full sized image.

**Example**

This URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/10152843929471041/picture

redirects to this URL:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10838228_10152843929471041_5251228402651650719_n.jpg

I removed the `720x720` from that URL to get this URL:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/s/10838228_10152843929471041_5251228402651650719_n.jpg

which is finally the full sized image.

I think, that I can achieve this modification with a regex pattern. But now is my question, how I can get the URL after the redirect from the original URL (the first one).

Any ideas or simpler solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you can get larger pictures:

```
/OBJECT-ID/picture?width=500&height=500
```

Or:

```
/OBJECT-ID/picture?type=large
```

Also take a look at answer in this thread: [Facebook Graph API : get larger pictures in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650730/facebook-graph-api-get-larger-pictures-in-one-request/27006154#27006154)

Edit: As this does not seem to work with Object IDs, you can just grab the image from this response:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10152843929471041
```

Look out for the "images" array.

Comment: That does not work for pictures gotten with object ids. I can only use thumbnail, normal and album

Comment: Thank you! Your Edit did it.

Answer (score 0):

One can also request the `images` collection of a `photo` object, then search for the **highest resolution entry**.

See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/). Code:

```
MyFacebookWrapper.getBestImage = function(photoId) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var params = { fields: "images" };

    FB.api("/" + photoId, "get", params,
        function (response) {
            console.log("MyFacebookWrapper.getBestImage, response:");
            console.log(response);

            var images = _.sortBy(response.images, 'width');
            var best = _.last(images)

            deferred.resolve(best); 
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Usage:

```
MyFacebookWrapper.getBestImage("photo Id ...").then(function(image) {
    console.log(image);
});
```