# Requesting Posts and Photos in a single request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'd like to know if there's a way to request a page's feed and also the pictures in each post. Getting each one separately isn't hard:

- **PAGE_ID**?fields=id,name,cover,fan_count,**posts**
- **POST_ID**?fields=**full_picture**

I've tried using batch. I wasn't able to get both in one request, I ended up with only the photos but not the posts (data) associated with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524411/2124535

Graph API request:

- **PAGE_ID**/posts?fields=picture,**full_picture**,attachments,description,**message**

or even simpler:

- **PAGE_ID**/posts?fields=**full_picture**,**message**