# Request Facebook profile picture with other information

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the js SDK and after the user has login in with FB I want to request the email, first name, last name and picture (a link to the picture).

This works:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name',
  (graph_response) ->
    ...
)
```

This also works, but the picture I get is super small (the same one that if I request `type=square` at `/me/picture`):

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture',
  (graph_response) ->
    ...
)
```

I know I can get a larger profile picture (big enough) doing this call:

```
FB.api('/me/picture?type=large&redirect=false',
  (graph_response) ->
    ...
)
```

Is there a way I can combine both in just one request? I have tried `/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture&type=large` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)
```

Alternatively, you can specifiy the sizes:

```
/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture.width(100).height(100)
```

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006154/757508